# I have an image file inside my Eclipse CDT project. How do I reference it in my code, so collaborators can use it when they run the code?

Tags: c++, eclipse, git, eclipse-cdt, organization

I'm currently working with a very small team on a project in C++ that involves displaying an image. We wish to be able to collaborate on it by sharing the code in a remote Git repository, and to this end, we have all agreed to switch to using Eclipse CDT instead of Xcode/Visual Studio/whatever else. Ideally, we should be able to clone the repository onto any machine with Eclipse CDT (and the relevant libraries) installed and build then successfully run the code there without any changes to it, but the current working version of the code uses the path of an image from my user directory. I have a copy of that image inside the project, and my question is, how can I use that so my teammates can use it too?

I've tried to use a relative path (which I've heard would find it relative to where the executable is run from rather than where it is anyhow), and I've tried substituting `PROJECT_PATH` for various prefixes of the full absolute path, but neither has worked. I'm also aware that the path of the image could be passed as a command-line argument, but I would prefer to have it inside the project, and although it could be appropriate in this situation I can think of many more in which it would not be (loading a sprite for a game, for example), and it just bothers me to not know how to do something that ought to be so basic.

A good bit of searching Stack Overflow has come up with many solutions to similar problems, but what little I've found for C++ has been for Visual Studio or Code::Blocks, and what little I've found for Eclipse has been for Java. It all seems to involve either "resource loaders" or directly shoving the relevant data into the binary, but I haven't been able to find documentation for these "resource loaders" and integrating the data into the executable using a hex editor seems like a lot of extra work to do each time the project gets built (plus I haven't a clue how to make it work with the library functionality I'm using).

The version of Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers that I'm using is 2018-12 (4.10.0), on macOS Mojave 10.4.2, and the single teammate I've interacted with so far is on some-or-another version of Ubuntu running presumably the same version of Eclipse. We should both be able to build and run the project, using the image, from the same files cloned from the same Git repository. The project is a "C++ Managed Build", because I couldn't figure out how to get the "CMake Project" to work (plus I don't know how to use CMake either way), with the "MacOSX GCC" toolchain (which come to think of it is probably another issue with moving the code between systems, but that's a problem for another day) because I have no idea how to use the "Cross GCC" toolchain.

This problem seems general enough that it shouldn't much matter, but the exact line of code that needs the path to the image currently looks like

```
cv::Mat image = cv::imread("/my/user/directory/Documents/8by8m.png");
```

using OpenCV 3.4.3, and with my attempts to use the copy of the image in the project directory the `Mat` has been coming up empty.

Comment: In the absence of other constraints, using a relative path seems like the simplest solution. You said you tried it and it didn't work. Can you elaborate: What did the line of code look like when you tried it? What directory was the image actually in? What directory was your executable in? What actually happened?

Comment: What happened was the `Mat` came up empty, I don't distinctly remember what path I used but I probably didn't try multiple of them...

Comment: Executable is located at `/my/user/directory/git/project_name/Project_Name/Debug/Project_Name` (no file extension), and from there the image should be `../8by8m.png`. After giving the path as that, with and without an extra `../`, all to no avail, I gave it the absolute path and it worked fine, then I gave it just `8by8m.png`, which I was sure I had already tried, and that worked too... huh. Guess I just had to be persistent, thanks! (Although it does still fail when run from a different directory.)